# Ansible: ufw is not a legal parameter in an ansible task or handler

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ansible

Trying to run an ansible installation on ubuntu 14.04

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts ruby-webapp.yml -t swap,ruby,deploy,mysql,nginx,ufw,import_data
```

I get

ERROR: ufw is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler

and I can't go forward with the rest of the installation.

Comment: does `ufw` exist in your ruby-webapp.yml playbook? `-t` is for *tags*, so it should be in there. You might need to post that file. What version of ansible-playbook?

Comment: @tedder42 I'm trying to install this https://github.com/nicolasblanco/ansible-sharetribe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ufw` was was added as a system module to Ansible 1.6 (see http://docs.ansible.com/ufw_module.html).

You are probably running an older version of Ansible on your control node (i.e., the machine where you are invoking the `ansible-playbook` command). Check your version with:

`ansible --version`

Upgrading depends on how you installed Ansible originally, but if you installed it to your system as root using `pip`, you can probably use:

`sudo pip install -U ansible`

(The `-U` means "update")

Edit: Just realized that you might be running Ubuntu 14.04 as your control node so I checked to see what version you get when you install Ansible with `apt-get`. As of this writing, it installs version 1.5.4, so if that's how you installed it, you definitely have the wrong version. You probably want to uninstall the OS package version and use one of the recommended installation techniques: http://docs.ansible.com/intro_installation.html#running-from-source

Something like:

```
sudo apt-get remove ansible
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install ansible
```

If you are missing `easy_install`, you may install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```